Quotes creation in Apex
I am writing a code to create Quote Record in Apex. There is a field on Quote -> Price Book. When I tried to set it using specific Price Book Id in Apex before inserting it is setting it Price Book field to blank after insert.
I tried to set it manually, but it is setting it to blank. But when I tried 'Edit Lines' Button, it is asking me first to set the Price book and then it is setting field Price Book to one which I selected. I want to update Quote price book update in Apex. How can I achieve it? Below is my current code which is not working.
    List<Pricebook2> listPriceBook = new List<Pricebook2>();

    Pricebook2 pb1 = [SELECT Id FROM Pricebook2 WHERE Name IN ('Online eCommerce Prices MinM') LIMIT 1];

    listPriceBook.add(pb1);

    Pricebook2 pb2 = [SELECT Id FROM Pricebook2 WHERE Name IN ('Online eCommerce Prices') LIMIT 1];

    listPriceBook.add(pb2);
    system.debug('listPriceBook - ' + listPriceBook);
    system.debug('Origin_Website_Domain - ' + Origin_Website_Domain);

    if(Origin_Website_Domain.tolowercase().contains('mates'))
    {
        system.debug('listPriceBook[0] - ' + listPriceBook[0]);
        quote.SBQQ__PriceBook__c = listPriceBook[0].Id;
    }
    else
    {
        system.debug('listPriceBook[1] - ' + listPriceBook[1]);
        quote.SBQQ__PriceBook__c = listPriceBook[1].Id;
    }

I am very new to CPQ
Best Regards,
Rahul
